# Hardness of a special case of maximum matching

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard, matching

> **Input**: A set of $n$ Users $U=\{u_1, ..., u_n\}$ and a set of $m$ products $I=\{i_1, ..., i_m\}$. Associated with each pair $u \in U$ and $i \in I$  is the probability $p_{u,i}$ of $u$ purchasing the product $i$.
>   **Task**: Assign each user exactly $k$ products so that the following objective function is maximized:
>   $$\sum_{i \in I(U)} ({1-\prod_{u\in U(i)}{(1-p_{u,i})}})$$
>   Where $I(U)\subseteq I$ is the set of products assigned to some user, and $U(i) \subseteq U$ is the set of users to whom a product $i$ is assigned.

Question: Is this problem NP-Hard?

Comment: What is your intuition? Have you tried constructing a reduction?

Comment: I tried to reduce from max-set-cover, but it did not work. Also, I was not able to construct a reduction to max-matching.

Comment: The intuition is to maximize the utilization of all resources, where resources are the products.